# The map $g \mapsto \phi_g$ forms an isometry from $L^q$ to $(L^p)^*$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Suppose $p$ and $q$ are conjugate exponents with $1 \leq q < \infty$. Then for each $g \in L^q$, the map
$$\phi_g(f) = \int fg$$
forms an isometry from $L^q$ into $(L^p)^*$.

Showing that $\|\phi_g\| \leq \|g\|_q$ is easy using Holders inequality. To prove $\|\phi_g\| \geq \|g\|_q$, I refer to Folland's proof where he introduces
$$f = \frac{|g|^{q-1}\overline{\text{sgn }g}}{\|g\|_q^{q-1}}.$$
From here the rest of the proof is easy to follow and is straight computation. However, I am conceptually confused on how this specific definition for $f$ proves the assertion for all functions $f \in L^q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence is wrong and probably shows the reason for your confusion: It is the map which sends $g$ to $\varphi_g$, that is $J(g):=\varphi_g$, which constitutes the isometry $J\colon L^q\to(L^p)^*$.
(To emphasize once more: $g$ is not fixed; $g$ is the argument of the isometry.)

What is true is that for fixed $g\in L^q$ the image $J(g)=\varphi_g$ is indeed an **element** of $(L^p)^*$. That is, for **fixed** $g$ you have a bounded linear functional on $L^p$, defined by $\varphi_g(f)=\int fg$. Moreover, the norm of this functional is (as you have shown)
$$\lVert\varphi_g\rVert_{(L^p)^*}=\sup_{\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}\le 1}\int fg=
\lVert g\rVert_{L_q}.$$
This means that the map $J\colon L^q\to (L^p)^*$ satisfies
$$\lVert J(g)\rVert=\lVert g\rVert\qquad\text{for every $g\in L^q$}$$
(the norm is the norm of $(L^p)^*$ or $L^q$, respectively.)
Since $J$ is linear, this means that
$$\lVert J(g_1)-J(g_2)\rVert=\lVert J(g_1-g_2)\rVert=\lVert g_1-g_2\rVert\qquad\text{for all $g_1,g_2\in L^q$,}$$
and this in turn means that $J$ is an isometriy.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. To summarize, we prove that the map $g \mapsto \phi_g$ is an isometry, not that for fixed $g$ the map $\phi_g(f)$ is an isometry. As a result, this is why it suffices to consider *any* $f \in L^p$ with norm 1 and so we choose $f$ as defined in the original post?

Comment: It is necessary to prove $\sup_{\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}\le1}\int fg=\lVert g\rVert_{L^q}$ $(*)$. Here “$\le$” follows by Hölders inequality (here you have to consider *all* $f$). For “$\ge$”, it suffices to find one $f$ with $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p}\le1$ for which $\int fg=\lVert g\rVert_{L^q}$: It follows that for this $f$ the left-hand side in $(*)$ attains its maximum $\lVert g\rVert_{L^q}$ (so, as a side result, you also see that the $\sup$ is in this case actually a $\max$).